# Centos httpd php version is different from the php version command line

Tags: php, linux, centos, redhat

I'm on Centos7 i have enable multiple php versions with remi repo like :

```
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php56
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php71
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php72
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php73
```

Then installed the packages :

```
yum install php{version}
yum install php{version}-php-{extension}
```

I have setup PHP5.6 like :

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php56
```

When i make php-v :

```
PHP 5.6.40 (cli) (built: Sep 29 2020 11:38:05)
```

But when i'm going to my phpinfo() file i get PHP Version 7.3.23

In centos/RH we can't make :

```
sudo a2enmod php56
```

so i'm confusing and i don't know why httpd interpret version 7.3.23

> How could i setup a PHP specific version to httpd?

[image]

Comment: **Danger**: PHP 5.x is beyond end of life, is not supported, and does not recieve security updates. **Do not use it after 31 Dec 2018**. (Also don't use PHP 7.0 after 10 Jan 2019  or 7.1 after 1 Dec 2019)

Comment: try installing [CWP](http://centos-webpanel.com/). It allows modifying the PHP version for apache and many more configurations without breaking your head.  Unless you want to play around with PHP fpm and fast-CGI handlers by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You are confused by 2 set of packages:

- base packages (php-*), 1 repository per version (remi-php##) and where you can install a single (and default) version
- SCL packages (php##-php-*) design for parallel installation of multiple versions

See the [repository FAQ.](https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/English-FAQ#scl)

If you want to install and run multiple versions, you have to use the SCLs and switch to FPM (instead of mod_php, this is the default way on CentOS 8).

In short, configure each FPM instance to run on a specific socket (network port or UDS), and configure Apache to use the proper version per virtual host, project, directory... using the SetHandler directive.

I recommend you read [PHP Configuration Tips](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/10/25/php-configuration-tips/)

You can also read [My PHP Workstation](https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2016/04/16/My-PHP-Workstation)